# Disable showing the Paypal Web browser on android

Tags: android, paypal, paypal-sandbox, braintree-sandbox, braintree-vault

I have integrated PayPal using Brain Tree using my Custom UI for PayPal Button on my native Android App. I have implemented the SDK for PayPal. when I tried to click my PayPal Button, I'm getting redirected to a Web Browser to PayPal to login using the credentials which is the expected behaviour as mentioned in there documents.  I have to disable showing the `URL` on the redirected Web Browser shown on the device on clicking the PayPal Button. How can I disable showing the WebBrowser URL on the redirected one? Please suggest me a work around for this.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot, [the URL is required](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/info-security-guidelines/#secure-applications).

With very few exceptions (some old apps with webview-based integrations) , everyone should *only* log into a PayPal account when they can see the URL, so they know they actually logging into PayPal.

Comment: thanks for the update.! so is there any way to get  the callback once I click on the Close Button shown on the Web browser to my app?

Comment: The close button is to cancel, so maybe onCancel https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/javascript-sdk/javascript-sdk-reference/#oncancel -- but if it doesn't fire then it should be returning the user to where they left off

Comment: getting the following error now :  ` java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method newInstance(Landroidx/appcompat/app/AppCompatActivity;Ljava/lang/String;)Lcom/braintreepayments/api/BraintreeFragment; in class Lcom/braintreepayments/api/BraintreeFragment; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.braintreepayments.api.BraintreeFragment' appears in /data/app/com.ust.fcs.wiwo-oRZTGn7OXhiznL9dD72Vtw==/base.apk)`  ,  ` mBraintreeFragment = BraintreeFragment.newInstance( MainActivity.this, btToken);
            Card.tokenize(mBraintreeFragment, cardBuilder);` on this line